# Working example for web worker with router

Tags: angular, web-worker

Is there any working example (plunkr) for angular2 BETA 6 web worker with router?

UPDATE:

My real issue is that there is no uptodate documentation on this for beta... but as  suggested...

My current issue is that I am able to load angular2, but the application itself is not initiated.

app/main.ts

```
import 'es6-shim';
import 'zone.js/dist/zone.min.js';
import 'reflect-metadata';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import {platform, Provider} from 'angular2/core';
import {
  WORKER_RENDER_APPLICATION,
  WORKER_RENDER_PLATFORM,
  WORKER_SCRIPT
} from 'angular2/platform/worker_render';

platform([WORKER_RENDER_PLATFORM])
  .application([
    WORKER_RENDER_APPLICATION,
    new Provider(WORKER_SCRIPT, {useValue: 'loader.js'})
  ]);
```

loader.js

```
importScripts('jspm_packages/system.src.js', 'config.js');
System.import('./app/worker')
    .catch(function (error) {
    console.error('ERROR @ loader :', error);
});
```

If I use .application function, I get error:

```
Error: Cannot use asyncronous app initializers with application. Use asyncApplication instead
```

worker.ts (.application function)

```
import {Provider, provide, platform, PLATFORM_DIRECTIVES} from 'angular2/core';
import {ROUTER_PROVIDERS} from 'angular2/router';
import {HTTP_PROVIDERS} from 'angular2/http';
import {App} from './app';

import {WORKER_APP_APPLICATION, WORKER_APP_PLATFORM, WORKER_APP_ROUTER} from 'angular2/platform/worker_app';

platform([WORKER_APP_PLATFORM])
    .application([
        WORKER_APP_APPLICATION,
        ROUTER_PROVIDERS,
        HTTP_PROVIDERS,
        WORKER_APP_ROUTER
    ])
     .then((ref) => {
         console.log('bootstrapping', ref);
         ref.bootstrap(App)
     });
```

If I use asyncApplication, than the first console log is written out, but in the bootstrap function the second not...

main.ts (.asyncApplication function)

```
import {Provider, provide, platform, PLATFORM_DIRECTIVES} from 'angular2/core';
import {ROUTER_PROVIDERS} from 'angular2/router';
import {HTTP_PROVIDERS} from 'angular2/http';
import {App} from './app';

import {WORKER_APP_APPLICATION, WORKER_APP_PLATFORM, WORKER_APP_ROUTER} from 'angular2/platform/worker_app';

platform([WORKER_APP_PLATFORM])
    .asyncApplication(() => {
        console.log('async app load');
        return Promise.resolve([
            ROUTER_PROVIDERS,
            WORKER_APP_ROUTER,
            WORKER_APP_APPLICATION,
            HTTP_PROVIDERS
        ]);
    })
     .then((ref) => {
         console.log('bootstrapping', ref);
         ref.bootstrap(App)
     });
```

How can I initiate the web worker part to be able to load the main component (App)?

Comment: this is  not a valid question as per SO criteria. you have to post your code instead of posting such question. either post your code where you failed or try searching tutorials for the same

Comment: I disagree, as it would definitelly would save time for me and for other if somebody would be able to point to some documentation/tutorial/example which is working... obviously I was searching for it and didnt find... so even if there is such it is not obvious to find...

Comment: You can read though the topics in the help menu. Just because you find it useful doesn't mean it's the right thing to do. There is a distinct close reason behind the `close` link above for questions that ask for libraries, books, ... or other external resources.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found this sample in the angular repository:
https://github.com/angular/angular/tree/master/modules/playground/src/web_workers/router

And actually the problem was that  I didn't include: WORKER_RENDER_ROUTER in the main.ts (UI part)

Also didnt add to the W_W part:

```
new Provider(LocationStrategy, {useClass: HashLocationStrategy})
```

So the full code if somebody interested:

worker.ts:

```
import 'es6-shim';
import 'zone.js/dist/zone.min.js';
import 'reflect-metadata';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import {Provider, provide, platform, PLATFORM_DIRECTIVES} from 'angular2/core';
import {ROUTER_PROVIDERS} from 'angular2/router';
import {HashLocationStrategy, LocationStrategy} from "angular2/router";
import {HTTP_PROVIDERS} from 'angular2/http';
import {App} from './app';

import {
    WORKER_APP_APPLICATION,
    WORKER_APP_PLATFORM,
    WORKER_APP_ROUTER
} from 'angular2/platform/worker_app';

let platformRef = platform([WORKER_APP_PLATFORM])
    .asyncApplication(null,[
        WORKER_APP_APPLICATION,
        WORKER_APP_ROUTER,
        HTTP_PROVIDERS,
        new Provider(LocationStrategy, {useClass: HashLocationStrategy})
    ]);
platformRef.then((ref) => {
    ref.bootstrap(App)
});
```

main.ts:

```
import 'es6-shim';
import 'zone.js/dist/zone.min.js';
import 'reflect-metadata';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import {platform, Provider} from 'angular2/core';
import {
  WORKER_RENDER_APP,
  WORKER_RENDER_PLATFORM,
  WORKER_SCRIPT,
  WORKER_RENDER_ROUTER
} from 'angular2/platform/worker_render';
import {BrowserPlatformLocation} from "angular2/src/router/browser_platform_location";
import {MessageBasedPlatformLocation} from "angular2/src/web_workers/ui/platform_location";

platform([WORKER_RENDER_PLATFORM])
  .application([
    WORKER_RENDER_APP,
    new Provider(WORKER_SCRIPT, {useValue: 'loader.js'}),
    WORKER_RENDER_ROUTER
  ]);
```